# Generated code that should generate multiple URLs at once

Tags: php, url, information-extraction

I would like to create a URL that takes input from different arrays to generate a search. The data I would like to retrieve is from NCBI. Below you can find the code I wrote. But I can't get it to work; I am stuck. Thank you in advance.

I should have something like this as result but i got nothing.
https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=gene&retmode=xml&retmax=10&sort=relevance&term=A20%20AND%20Homo%20sapiens%20%5borgn%5d%20AND%20alive%5bprop%5d

```
<blink>

</blink>
```

`$eutils = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils";`
`$db = "gene";`
`$gene_symbols = array("A20","HBB","ABO");`

`$species = array("homo sapiens", "Escherichia coli","Saccharomyces cerevisiae")`;
`$links = array();`

```
foreach ($gene_symbols as $key => $GS){ 
   $SP = $species[$key];
   $query = "$GS AND $SP [orgn] AND alive";

   $esearch = "$eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=$db&retmode=xml&retmax=10&sort=relevance&term=";

   echo $esearch; 
   $links[] = get($esearch.$query);   }
   foreach($links as $lk){
      xml = simplexml_load_file($lk) or die("feed not loading");    }

   var_dump(xml);
```

Comment: You have syntax errors first clear those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$eutils = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi";

   $databank = "gene";
   $gene_symbols = array("A20","HBB","ABO");

   $species = array("homo sapiens", "Escherichia coli","Saccharomyces cerevisiae");


    foreach($gene_symbols as $value => $GS){
        $Species = $species[$value];


        $esearch = "$GS%AND%alive[prop]%AND+$Species[orgn]";
        $esearch_test = "$eutils?db=$databank&retmode=xml&retmax=10&sort=relevance&term=$esearch";
        $result = file_get_contents($esearch_test);
        echo "Query: " . $esearch_test. "<br \>\n";
        echo "Result: " . $result . "<br \>\n";

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
        echo "Count:<br \>\n";
        echo $xml->Count;
        $C =  $xml->Count;
        echo $C;
    }
```